# Significance of the trace in isomorphic matrix fields

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

The field $\mathbb{Q}(\operatorname{i})$ has an isomorphic matrix field of degree two. The isomorphism is
$$\varphi:x+\operatorname{i}\!y \longmapsto \left[\begin{array}{cc} x & -y \\ y & x \end{array}\right]$$
Besides the obvious connections between addition and multiplication, it can be shown that the determinant operation is related to the modulus operation: $\det\left[\varphi(z)\right] = |z|^2$. Moreover, the transpose operation is related to the conjugate operartion: $\overline{z} \mapsto \varphi(z)^{\top}$.

Since the trace plays such a role in linear algebra and Lie groups/algebras, e.g. is invariant under changes of basis and is related to the derivative of the determinant, I am lead to ask:

What significance does $\operatorname{tr}\left[\varphi(z)\right]=2\Re(z)$ have in the theory of complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace comes into play very much in the theory of algebraic number fields (= subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ that are finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$). There the size of the matrices equals the degree of the field extension. The bilinear trace form $$(x,y)=tr(xy)$$ in particular plays a role a bit like the inner product. Even in the complex case the inner product of $z_1$ and $z_2$ (when viewed as 2-dimensional vectors over the reals) is given by the formula
$$\langle z_1,z_2\rangle=tr(\phi(z_1z_2^*)).$$

Answer (score 2):

Does $\operatorname{tr} \left[\varphi(z)\right] = \log \det\left[ \varphi(e^z)\right] $ count?
Note that $\varphi(e^z)=e^{\varphi(z)}$.

Comment: I was going to say $e^{\mathrm{tr}(\varphi(z))}=\det(\varphi(e^z))$, then I realized that this is the same thing.